# Sharepoint GetListItemChangesSinceToken CURL request in PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to get the latest changes from my documentlist in Sharepoint using PHP and [GetListItemChangesSinceToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292554.aspx). I'm using [phpSPO](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) as a SDK since there aren't any official Sharepoint SDK's for PHP.

So far I have this:

```
$payload = array(
        'query' => array(
            '__metadata' => array('type' => 'SP.ChangeLogItemQuery'),
            'ViewName' => '',
            'QueryOptions'=> '<QueryOptions><Folder>Shared Documents</Folder></QueryOptions>'
        )
    );

    $headers = array();
    $headers["X-HTTP-Method"] = "MERGE";

    $changes = $this->request->executeQueryDirect($this->settings->URL . "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/GetListItemChangesSinceToken", $headers, $payload);
```

Which returns: `{"error":{"code":"-2147467261, System.ArgumentNullException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: query"}}}`

I've tried changing the `X-HTTP-Method` and changing the array to fit the documented JSON/XML request (XML in JSON objects, come on Microsoft)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First approach**

The following example demonstrates how to utilize [`GetListItemChangesSinceToken method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.lists.getlistitemchangessincetoken.aspx):

```
$listTitle = "Documents";
$payload = array(
    'query' => array(
        '__metadata' => array('type' => 'SP.ChangeLogItemQuery'),
        'ViewName' => '',
        'QueryOptions'=> '<QueryOptions><Folder>Shared Documents</Folder></QueryOptions>'
    )
);

$request = new ClientRequest($webUrl,$authCtx);
$options = array(
    'url' => $webUrl . "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('$listTitle')/GetListItemChangesSinceToken",
    'data' => json_encode($payload),
    'method' => 'POST'
);
$response = $request->executeQueryDirect($options);

//process results
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('z', '#RowsetSchema');
$rows = $xml->xpath("//z:row");
foreach($rows as $row) {
    print (string)$row->attributes()["ows_FileLeafRef"] . "\n";
}
```

**Second approach**

Since [SharePoint REST Client SDK for PHP](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) now supports [`GetListItemChangesSinceToken method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.lists.getlistitemchangessincetoken.aspx), the previous example could be invoked like this:

```
$list = $ctx->getWeb()->getLists()->getByTitle($listTitle);
$query = new ChangeLogItemQuery();
//to request all the items set ChangeToken property to null  
$query->ChangeToken = "1;3;e49a3225-13f6-47d4-a146-30d9caa05362;635969955256400000;10637059";
$items = $list->getListItemChangesSinceToken($query);
$ctx->executeQuery();
foreach ($items->getData() as $item) {
    print "[List Item] $item->Title\r\n";
}
```

More examples could be found [here](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/blob/master/examples/change_examples.php) under [phpSPO](https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO) repository.

Comment: Thank you so  **so** much Vadim

Comment: Good question, unfortunately AFAIK no, this particular endpoint returns XML payload(similar to asmx legacy resultset), no matter what JSON control header is specified.